# Build coffeescript on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, coffeescript

does anyone know how to build coffeescript on Heroku?

I have a nodejs web application, with some client side resources (all written in coffee), and want to get heroku to build the coffee script, without me having to build locally and upload the target.

I have tried [Aergonaut](https://github.com/aergonaut/heroku-buildpack-coffeescript) build pack, as instructed - but gives me the following error:

```
       /tmp/node-node-H5WL/bin/node: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 !     Failed to install --production dependencies with npm
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Coffeescript app
```

*Package.json:*

```
{
  "name": "WebClient",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3",
    "debug": "~2.0.0",
    "jade": "~1.6.0",
    "coffee-script": "1.8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: is coffeescript included in your pagackage.json?

Comment: yes, I've now included in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i figured it out, using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).
Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "SSWebClient",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "postinstall": "gulp",
    "prestart": "npm install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.11.*",
    "body-parser": "1.12.*",
    "cookie-parser": "1.3.*",
    "morgan": "1.5.*",
    "serve-favicon": "2.2.*",
    "nconf": "0.7.*",
    "debug": "2.1.*",
    "underscore": "1.8.*",
    "jade": "1.9.*",
    "coffee-script": "1.9.*",
    "less": "2.4.*",
    "gulp": "3.8.*",
    "gulp-coffee": "2.3.*",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.3.*",
    "gulp-rename": "*",
    "gulp-less": "*",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "*",
    "gulp-develop-server": "*",
    "gulp-livereload": "3.7.*",
    "gulp-cached": "*",
    "del": "*"
  }
}
```

Your gulpfile (coffeescript in my case) is below. I've included the LESS config as well for interest sake. I've also included `gulp-load-plugins`, makes the code more succinct.
Note: you need the **stage** task for Heroku.

```
gulp = require 'gulp'
plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')()

compileCoffee = ->
  gulp.src './src/**/*.coffee'
  .pipe plugins.cached 'compileCoffee'
  .pipe plugins.sourcemaps.init()
  .pipe plugins.coffee()
  .pipe plugins.sourcemaps.write()
  .on 'error', (err) -> console.log err.toString()
  .pipe gulp.dest './target'

compileLess = ->
  gulp.src './src/client/**/*.less'
  .pipe plugins.cached 'compileLess'
  .pipe plugins.less()
  .on 'error', (err) -> console.log err.toString()
  .pipe gulp.dest './target/client'

gulp.task 'build', ['compileCoffee', 'compileLess']

gulp.task 'stage', ['build']
```

Comment: I`ve just made a sample of it: https://github.com/lfreneda/how-to-coffeescript-on-heroku